# Combine two dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames.

```
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(c(2,3),c(4,5)))
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,6),c(9,8,7)))
```

I want to combine them and the result is like:

```
df3 <- data.frame(cbind(c(2,2,2,3,3,3), c(4,4,4,5,5,5),c(1,2,6,1,2,6), c(9,8,7,9,8,7)))
```

Is there any method to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use `merge` and join them by `NULL` to get a cartesian product of two dataframes.

```
merge(df1, df2, by = NULL)

#  X1.x X2.x X1.y X2.y
#1    2    4    1    9
#2    3    5    1    9
#3    2    4    2    8
#4    3    5    2    8
#5    2    4    6    7
#6    3    5    6    7
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a very convenient way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(df1, setNames(df2, paste0(names(df2), "_1")))
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     X1    X2  X1_1  X2_1
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     4     1     9
2     2     4     2     8
3     2     4     6     7
4     3     5     1     9
5     3     5     2     8
6     3     5     6     7
```

---

Or with `expand_grid`

```
expand_grid(df1, df2, .name_repair = "unique")
```

Comment: Thanks, Akrun! I'm not familiar with tidyr. Could you please explain the grammar of crossing and expand_grid?